# javascript regex match works but replace doesnt work

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to use regex replace with a regex I have. When I use the match method it returns the array with the proper index and match but when I use replace and add the replace string it wouldnt work.

```
var a = "$#,##0.00".match("[\\d+-,#;()\\.]+");
console.log(a);
```

Returns `["#,##0.00", index: 1, input: "$#,##0.00"]`.

```
var b = "$#,##0.00".replace("[\\d+-,#;()\\.]+","");
console.log(b);
```

Returns `$#,##0.00` whereas I expect it to return just the `$`

Can someone point out what am I doing incorrectly? Thanks
Link to the example is:

```js
var a = "$#,##0.00".match("[\\d+-,#;()\\.]+");
console.log(a);
var b = "$#,##0.00".replace("[\\d+-,#;()\\.]+","");
console.log(b);
```

Comment: You're passing a string to `replace()` ?

Comment: yes, an empty string as I just want $ as my result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**`.match`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) only accepts regexps. So if a string is provided `.match` will explicitly convert it to a regexp using `new RegExp`.

[**`.replace`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) however accepts both a string (which will be taken literally as the search) or a regexp, you have to pass in a regexp if you want it to use a regexp.

```
var b = "$#,##0.00".replace(new RegExp("[\\d+-,#;()\\.]+"), "");
//                          ^^^^^^^^^^^                  ^
```

or using a regexp literal:

```
var b = "$#,##0.00".replace(/[\d+-,#;()\.]+/, "");
```

Comment: ohh! I did not know that, I thought replace by default consumes a reg exp. Thanks for pointing that

Comment: +1 to answer, just pointing another possible way: var a = "$#,##0.00";
var b = a.replace(a.match("[\\d+-,#;()\\.]+"), "");
Also works, because a.match(...) will be a string

Comment: @GabrielMilitello The fastest way to get from USA to Japan is over the atlantic ocean, eh? :D.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir :D just one thing, replace with "", not "a"... Think OP edited the question...

Comment: yeah, I edited it, that was a typo. Thanks @Gabriel for pointing another way.